# Morley Phenomena for Special Families of Reals

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Vaught's Conjecture is a dual form of Continuum Hypothesis in model theory. It asserts that for each complete consistent theory $T$ in a countable language if $I(T,\aleph_{0})>\aleph_{0}$ then $I(T,\aleph_0)=2^{\aleph_{0}}$.

The best known result here is proved by Morley.

**For each complete theory $T$ in a countable language if $I(T,\aleph_{0})>\aleph_{1}$ then $I(T,\aleph_0)=2^{\aleph_{0}}$.**

We call this kind of overspill from $\aleph_1$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$, a Morley phenomenon.

**Question.** For which non-trivial properties $P$ is the following true?

**If $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of reals (subsets of $\omega$) with $|\mathcal{F}|>\aleph_{1}$ and each set $X\in \mathcal{F}$ satisfies the property $P$ then $|\mathcal{F}|=2^{\aleph_0}$.**

In the other words, for which kind of reals do we have a Morley phenomenon for families  of that particular type of reals? Is there any correspondence between these type of reals and countable models of a complete theory in a countable language?

Comment: "This phenomenon is..." or "These phenomena are...."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classical example is   ${\mathbf\Pi}^1_1$ sets of reals.
We say that $X\subset \mathbb R$ is ${\mathbf\Pi}^1_1$ if the complement of the projection
of a Borel set in ${\mathbb R}^n$.  Any such set of cardinality greater than $\aleph_1$ has cardinality continuum.

Comment: One then continues this in the presence of large cardinals through the projective hierarchy and beyond.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Would you please explain more?

Comment: Your answer is very nice, Prof. Marker. Would you please provide more examples (if there is any)?

Comment: @CCD This is a standard result, and is not really model theoretic. Jech's set theory book should have at least a sketch and references.